# retrieve/echo updated user account balance with php mysql

Tags: php

I have created a mysql table with these columns.

```
user_id, user_name, user_password, user_email, user_balance
```

I ran this query on phpmyadmin and it worked successfully changing the user_balance to 4.

```
UPDATE `members` 
SET `user_balance`=`user_balance` + 4
WHERE `user_id`= 2
```

I have the user balance stored in the `$_SESSION` when the user logs in and on the following page their balance is displayed in the header. The problem is that if I log in to the user account and I run the query above it will not update the user_balance unless I log out and then log back in.

```
$_SESSION['user_balance'] = $result->user_balance;

<?php echo $_SESSION['user_balance'] ?>
```

Is there an efficient way to have the current `user_balance` displayed after a refresh of the page?

Comment: Use a cache and invalidate it when you make changes.

Comment: What's the query you run to get the results? When is it run?

Comment: How would I be able to do that? Do you have a link so I can have an idea.

Comment: @Micah this is the query and it is ran when the user first logs in. SELECT *
                         FROM members
                         WHERE user_name = '{$this->user_name}' AND user_password = '{$this->user_password}'

Comment: OK. I have figured out how to have the the updated balance displayed but now I want it displayed like this: 0.00000 or 1.00000 instead of 0 or 1. In the mysql database I tried changing the type to INT, Float and, Decimal but neither of them would work how I wanted it to.

Comment: 2 things might have caused it, 1) you didn't setup the DB correctly, have you tried DOUBLE(5, 5) (or float).  2) you didn't handle the floating point number correctly in your code after you've extract the number from DB. check your code where you store the value and also the code where you display it.